# ZF2 Doctrine with Symfony < OR null query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, null, zend-framework2

How do I write this "WHERE" condition in a way which is compatible with Doctrine?

```
( ( `translations_es_google`.`translation_date` < `translations_masters`.`translation_date` ) OR ( `translations_es_google`.`translation_date` is null ) )
```

What I have tried (unsuccessfully) are:

```
$query1
    ->andWhere('((t.translationDate < m.translationDate) OR (t.translationDate is NULL))');

$query1
    ->andWhere('(t.translationDate < m.translationDate) OR (t.translationDate is NULL)');
```

Table alias for the Doctrine query are

- t represents the table translations_es_google
- m represents the table translations_masters

When I remove this "andWhere" condition the rest of the QueryBuilder query executes as expected.

The query I am trying to execute is

```
SELECT 
    `translations_masters`.`translation_key` , `translations_masters`.`text_domain` , `translations_masters`.`translation_date` 
FROM 
    `translations_masters` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `translations_es_google` ON ( ( `translations_masters`.`text_domain` = `translations_es_google`.`text_domain` ) AND ( `translations_masters`.`translation_key` =`translations_es_google`.`translation_key` ) ) 
WHERE 
    `translations_masters`.`language_iso` NOT LIKE 'es-Google' AND ( ( `translations_es_google`.`translation_date` < `translations_masters`.`translation_date` ) OR ( `translations_es_google`.`translation_date` is null ) ) 
GROUP BY 
    `translations_masters`.`translation_key` , `translations_masters`.`text_domain` 
ORDER BY 
    `translations_masters`.`translation_date` ASC
```

As requested the QueryBuilder version of this query is:

```
$query1 = $this->entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('m.textDomain , m.translationKey , m.translationDate , m.translationDate AS translationMasterDate , t.translationDate')
    ->from(
        'AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\Translations' . $explode1 . $explode2,
        't'
    )
    ->leftJoin(
        'AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\TranslationsMasters',
        'm',
        Join::WITH,
        '(m.textDomain = t.textDomain) AND (m.translationKey = t.translationKey)'
    )
    ->groupBy('m.textDomain , m.translationKey')
    ->orderBy(
        'm.translationDate',
        'ASC'
    )
    ->setMaxResults('1');

$query1
    ->andWhere(
        $query1->expr()
               ->notLike(
                   'm.languageIso',
                   ':languageIso'
               )
    )
    ->setParameter(
        'languageIso',
        $value
    );

$query1->andWhere(
    $query1->expr()->orX(
        't.translationDate < m.translationDate',
        't.translationDate IS NULL'
    )
);

$result1 = $query1->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
```

The output of **$query1->getQuery()->getSQL()** is

```
SELECT 
    t0_.text_domain AS text_domain_0, t0_.translation_key AS translation_key_1, t0_.translation_date AS translation_date_2, t0_.translation_date AS translation_date_3, t1_.translation_date AS translation_date_4
FROM 
    thev1010_theverseoftheday.translations_es_google t1_ 
LEFT JOIN 
    thev1010_theverseoftheday.translations_masters t0_ ON ((t0_.text_domain = t1_.text_domain) AND (t0_.translation_key = t1_.translation_key)) 
WHERE 
    t0_.language_iso NOT LIKE ? AND (t1_.translation_date < t0_.translation_date OR t1_.translation_date IS NULL) 
GROUP BY 
    t0_.text_domain, t0_.translation_key 
ORDER BY 
    t0_.translation_date ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

- The **?** value is 'es-Google'

The output of **$query1->getQuery()->getDQL();** is

```
SELECT 
    m.textDomain , m.translationKey , m.translationDate , m.translationDate AS translationMasterDate , t.translationDate 
FROM 
    AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\TranslationsEsGoogle t 
LEFT JOIN 
    AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\TranslationsMasters m WITH (m.textDomain = t.textDomain) AND (m.translationKey = t.translationKey) 
WHERE 
    m.languageIso NOT LIKE :languageIso AND (t.translationDate < m.translationDate OR t.translationDate IS NULL) 
GROUP BY 
    m.textDomain , m.translationKey 
ORDER BY 
    m.translationDate ASC
```

- The **?** value is 'es-Google'

Comment: Show your complete query (queryBuilder)

Comment: As requested I've edited my original post to show the query.

Comment: Can you show the resulting query of your current code with `$query1->getQuery()->getSQL()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `orX` expression?

You can try it this way:

```
$query1->andWhere(
    $query1->expr()->orxX(
         't.translationDate < m.translationDate',
         't.translationDate IS NULL'
    )
);
```

`orX` gives you the ability to add multiple conditions, separated by comma. 
You can also separate your `orX` condition to its own variable and pass everything added to it to `andWhere` condition.

Comment: Can you try displaying the query with `->getQuery()->getDQL()` ? Do you something wrong with the syntax? Could you provide the dump so we can inspect it too, with the addition we made with `orX`?

Comment: I've added the results of ->getQuery()->getDQL() and updated $query1->getQuery()->getSQL() with the use of orX

Comment: That's weird. The query looks fine. You provided a version of SQL syntax that you're trying to achieve with query builder. Did you tried to execute the sql in phpmyadmin (or other sql management tool) to see if there are actually any results returned?

Comment: I've finally found my mistake. I had the "join" tables in reverse order.  Thank you for the effort you made to help me.